# Unable to call a variable in a function from another package to another non-main function golang

Tags: go, import, package

I know there are lots of other questions like this but they are all about calling a function from a main.go, which is not my case. In file1.go I have a function like this:

```
func (c *cubicSender) InRecovery() bool {
    return c.largestAckedPacketNumber <= c.largestSentAtLastCutback && c.largestAckedPacketNumber != 0
}

func (c *cubicSender) InSlowStart() bool {
    return c.GetCongestionWindow() < c.GetSlowStartThreshold()
}
```

I want to assign these functions into variables IR and ISS in file2.go. So when a function is called:

```
if IR == true {
            fmt.Println(pathID, pth.sentPacketHandler.GetCongestionWindow(), pth.sentPacketHandler.GetBytesInFlight(), pth.rttStats.SmoothedRTT(), time.Now().UnixNano(), "SS")
} else if ISS == true {
            fmt.Println(pathID, pth.sentPacketHandler.GetCongestionWindow(), pth.sentPacketHandler.GetBytesInFlight(), pth.rttStats.SmoothedRTT(), time.Now().UnixNano(), "IR")
}
```

How can I do that?

*Edit: I have imported the package, which has file1.go in file2.go.

Comment: The files here are irrelevant, what's important is in which package have you declared the function, and in which package are you trying to use that function. Can you please provide these two bits of information?

Comment: the function is declared in package congestion. And I want to use it file2.go which is in package quic. I have import in package congestion in file2.go

Comment: Then have quic/file2.go import package `congestion` and then to execute the function you can call it like so `congestion.MyFunction()`. Just like when you're calling `fmt.Println`, you first import `fmt` and then you can call `fmt.Println(...)`.

Comment: yes, I know I should be able to do that. But it still shows the function is not declared in file2.go. When I try to use if congestion.InRecovery()==true { }

Comment: `InRecovery` seems to be declared as a *method* of `*cubicSender`, not as a function. You cannot call methods just by specifying the package in which they are declared, you need an instance of the type on which the method is declared and then you can call the method by qualifying it with the instance variable's name.

Comment: cubicSender is a struct in file1.go. So should I make another struct in file2.go? which equivalent to cubicSender? Then how can I qualify it?

Comment: You don't need to declare a new type. You just need an *instance* of `cubicSender` to be able to call a method on it. For example `var cs = new(cubicSender); cs.InRecovery()`.

Comment: Note that if you want to use the method `InRecovery` outside of the package in which it is declared, you need to either *export* the type on which the method is defined (i.e. `cubicSender`), or you need to somehow provide access to an instance of the *unexported* type, e.g. via an exported variable, or function.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/IeDeKuJ09xR

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I have been able to call both of these function. How can   I mark your comments as the answer?

Comment: I've added an answer, you can accept that if it's satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InRecovery` seems to be declared as a method of `*cubicSender`, not as a function. You cannot call methods just by specifying the package in which they are declared, you need an instance of the type on which the method is declared and then you can call the method by qualifying it with the instance variable's name.

Note that if you want to use the method `InRecovery` outside of the package in which it is declared, then you need to either *export* the type on which the method is defined (i.e. `cubicSender`), or you need to somehow provide access to an instance of the unexported type, e.g. via an exported variable, or function.

For example in `congestion/file1.go`:

```
package congestion

type cubicSender struct {
    // ...
}

// exported function to provide access to the unexported type
func NewCubicSender() *cubicSender {
    return &cubicSender{
        // ...
    }
}

func (c *cubicSender) InRecovery() bool {
    return false
}
```

And in `quic/file2.go`:

```
package quic

import "path/to/congestion"

func foobar() {

    c := congestion.NewCubicSender() // initialize an instance of cubicSender
    if c.InRecovery() { // call InRecovery on the instance
        // ...
    }

}
```